# ereg_replace or preg_replace function

Tags: php, preg-replace, ereg-replace

I will like to replace any numeric character from the 12th position of variable `$key` with an empty string: `$key` variable has 12 characters + incremented numeric characters. For example:

```
IODN4YFK5XKV1
GYDN4YFK5XKV2
P3FU4YFK5XKV3
```

Bellow is my current line of php code:

```
$data = ereg_replace( "[0-9]+$", "", $_REQUEST['code'] );
```

Problem: If my `$key = HXGE1SR9OWM428`, the last 3 digits (428) will be removed but I'll like to remove only the digits as from the 12th position so that my result will be `$data = HXGE1SR9OWM4`.

Comment: he didn't say it has to be with ereg_* :P

Comment: do you need to replace only the 12-th char or everything after it ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `substr()`?

```
 $data = substr($_REQUEST['code'], 0, 12);
```

FYI, `ereg_*` is deprecated in the newer version of PHP

Comment: wow, did you even read the question? "I will like to replace any `numeric` character from the 12th position of variable $key with an empty string" your code will drop whatever after 12th position.

Comment: @mask8, Yes I did, and he doesnt say he wants to replace it ONLY if it is numeric. He stated the 12th character is numeric. He also said that he wants to replace it. Not the same thing.

Comment: yes that's true. but since my code does what @EngineerDeclan wants, do you see why I'm getting down vote lol mine even followed he wanted ereg_replace or preg_replace ha

Comment: @mask8, i hear ya. And it works, which is why I dont understand why you got downvoted. All i did was offer an alternative, heck, that's pretty much what substr was made for. I hate when people downvote and never say why.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this: *I'm using preg_replace instead.

```
$data = preg_replace( "/^([\w]{12})[0-9]+$/", "$1", $_REQUEST['code'] );
```

Comment: isn't `\w\d` redundant? I believe `\w` includes digits. Thus the following pattern should do as good: `/^(\w{12})\d+$/`

Answer (score 0):

Using deprecated `ereg_*` as shown in your question you would do:

```
$data = ereg_replace('^([A-Z0-9]{12})[0-9]+', '\1', $_REQUEST['code']);
```

If lower-case letters need to be included in the pattern, simply change `ereg_replace` to `eregi_replace`.

However, a better approach would be to use the `preg_*` functions group instead:

```
$data = preg_replace('/^(\w{12})\d+$/', '$1', $_REQUEST['code']);
```

Again, for lower-case letters, just add `i` at the end of the pattern, so it's `'/^(\w{12})\d+$/i'`